# how to close a button in one click without id but with a class

Tags: javascript

I would like to hide a button or close it but without ID just with a class
I tried with the code below but it doesn't work

```
<input type="button" value="Click" class="visible">
<script>
input = document.getElementsByClassName('.visible');

input.addEventListener('click', function(){
   input.style.display = 'none';
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name suggests, `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements, where `document.getElementById` returns a single element.

So, you'll need to loop over the elements and install the handler on each one in turn. This is easiest if you convert it to an Array first:

```js
inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('visible'); // not ".visible"

Array.from(inputs).forEach(function(input) {
   input.addEventListener('click', function(){
      input.style.display = 'none';
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but it doesn't work

Comment: No need to create new array from HTMLCollection. Use  for loop  `for (const input of inputs){}` instead of `forEach`

Comment: @Anilkumar That will not work in general because of the closure around `input`

Comment: @paul It does work, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o2pew0j4/). However, it will only install the click handler on elements that exist when the code is run.

Answer (score 1):

when using getElementByClassName, you shouldn't include the `.`.

instead it should be:

```
input = document.getElementsByClassName('visible');
```

I think you are confusing vanilla JS with Jquery, where you would have to use the `.` before a class name.

Edit:

It should also be noted that input will return a collection, so make sure to select the element you want to add the eventListener to (or loop over the entire collection if you want to assign it to all elements that have the class `visible`).

Comment: thanks for the answer but even without the dot it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here your element `input = document.getElementsByClassName('.visible')` will return an array of elements, so you need to extract the particular element from that array and then call the eventListener. It will work then.

Comment: thank you for the answer, can you give me an example

Comment: input = document.getElementsByClassName('visible');
    
    input[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log("clcked")
       input[0].style.display = 'none';
    });
    </script>












this might work

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
input = document.getElementsByClassName('.visible');
```

To

```
let input = document.getElementsByClassName('visible');
```